# Terminal commands for file backup

Tags: hard-drive, terminal, backup, macbook-pro, disk-utility

MacBook Pro late 2012
Having issues with OSX and hard drive 
Have been told to get the hardware  upgraded however in the meantime need to back up files

I do plan to take a disk image however as an extra precaution thinking of copying the specific files I know I created after my last time machine back up on a separate external hard drive

Could you please help me with the terminal commands I shoukd use in disk utility in the recovery mode

I am a total novice so please help with instructions and details 
. Heck I don’t even know my username ( atkeast not sure) and don’t know the path to the documents Etc

Please help

Comment: "issues with OSX and hard drive" - What issues, what's been done so far? Why are you down to the desperate measure of trying to blindly copy data out from Terminal as a rescue attempt? Do you have access to another Mac? Whay hardware are you going to be upgrading, the drive or the entire Mac?

Comment: Yes I am thinking of changing the hard drive based on the information received from Apple support over the phone

Comment: Desperate to get my hands on the data . No I don’t have any other computer either . So was hoping to make backups before I touch the hard drive

Comment: Tried updating the OS however it continues to give me the file with a blinking question mark

Comment: The safest thing to do is swap the drives, get a fresh OS on the new drive & mount the other read-only from a USB interface. Right now every time you try to do something else to it, you risk losing more data. BTW, the time to make backups is **before** you need them, not after. What you're trying to do now is not backup, it's recovery.